# Do you feel like you're using conditional when using "would" for past tense ?

Tags: tense, conditional-constructions, will-would

I was taught "would" has a value of past tense, like in :

> When I was a child, my father would take me to the park after school

But the more I hear it and use it, the more it "feels" like conditional and I think of it more as a "would" than as a "used to", as in

> I used to take the bus but I walk now.

In my language both translate to the same tense, so our teachers pretty much told us "just think of it as a past tense and not a conditional". Now I kind of see the "logic" for there to be a conditional in those sentences.

Native speakers, do you feel like you're using conditional or a past tense ? Or neither ?

Comment: Would can be used to express uncertainty and conditions. "If i had a hammer, **I'd** (would) hammer in the morning." Indeed in this case, you never had a hammer (past) nor do you have one now (present).

Comment: Would is regularly used for both of these possible meanings, and can be used in several other ways. Consult a good dictionary like this one: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/would

Comment: To answer your question: in your first example. a native speaker does not feel that they are using conditional at all. _Would_ has two distinct meanings, and we don't mix them up.

Answer (score 2):

One of the uses of the verb *would* is to talk about habitual action that took place in the past.

OED says of *will:*

> **27.** (Cf. 8.) Was (were) accustomed to; used to.
>   ...
>    <sup>1470–85   Malory *Morte d'Arthur* ix. xxxvii. 399   Euery day syr Palomydes *wold* repreue sir Tristram of old hate betwixe them.
>
>   ...
>
>    1847   Thackeray *Vanity Fair* (1848) xxi. 181   The girls would ask her..for a little music, and she would sing her three songs.</sup>

When native speakers use *would* as in your example, we are using it as *both* a conditional and past tense, and this is as it should be, since *would* is the past tense of *will.* The condition is fulfilled in the past, and it is *will's* original implication of intention that provides the sense that the action is habitual.

I am venturing far from grammar here, but perhaps one of the reasons for your observation:

> *"the more I hear it and use it, the more it "feels" like conditional..."*

...is that you are beginning to think in English, and that some of historic sense of the verb *will* is starting to influence that thinking. Consider that if a British person in 1594 CE said:

> Husband wants me home, but I would go to market...

...she was expressing the thought: *I firmly intend to go to market.* *Would* is not just an auxiliary that puts *go* in a future tense or makes the "going" conditional. Even today, when we use *would* to talk about the past:

> She's gone, but in the past, I would gather flowers for her...

...the statement has a greater affect than:

> She's gone, but in the past, I used to gather flowers for her...

*Used to* merely expresses that the action was habitual and in the past. *Would* implies also that the speaker actively *desired* the action in preference to other actions.

#### Historical note

Originally, this usage of *would* to describe action in the past might also imply some of the original sense of *will* as *intending or desiring,* as in one of the OED's earliest citations above:

> 1470–85   Malory *Morte d'Arthur* ix. xxxvii. 399   Euery day syr Palomydes *wold* repreue sir Tristram of old hate betwixe them.

In this passage, Malory describes the imprisoned nobleman Palomydes and his daily reminders to his fellow prisoner Tristram of the enmity between them; yet, when Palomydes sees that Tristram is ill, he comforts him instead:

> But when syr Palomydes sawe the fallynge of sekenesse of syr Tristram, thenne was he heuy for hym / and comforted him in alle the best wyse he coude.

The use of *wold* here describes both past action and Palomydes's *will* to continue haranguing Tristram: and then, seeing that Tristram is ill, he no longer *desires* to remind him of their past conflict. This sense would have been clear to a reader in Malory's time. Malory could have used the simple past *repreued* here, but may well have chosen *wold repreue* for this reason.

As centuries passed, this sense of intention or desire in most such usages was lost, and in most modern uses like the one in this question *would* connotes only *used to.*

Comment: I disagree with your last part : one could say "*When I was I college sometimes I would cry while doing my homework*", but there is no *intention* or *will* to cry, at all.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Exactly: *My father would take us to the park even though he didn't want to*. *Would* here does not refer to *willingness*.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat maybe *would* has more than one meaning, and more than one use? The OED has at least 27 different meanings. I think P.E. Dant was explaining the meaning of *would* as it is used in your sentence.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat "A trace" is how I originally phrased it, and I certainly should have added "sometimes" and included an example or two. Not every usage implies willingness, and not every speaker uses the verb in that way, and in modern usage it is usually merely another way to say _used to._ See edits...